# How do I get TWebBrowser in Delphi XE2 to run?

Tags: delphi, crash, delphi-xe2, twebbrowser

The TWebBrowser component in Delphi XE2 seems to be seriously buggy. Is there some sort of code I have to run in order to instantiate it in some special way?

1. Create new Delphi project
2. Drop a TWebBrowser component onto the form.
3. In Form1.FormCreate() call WebBrowser1.GoHome (to google).

If I compile this 32-bit and go to some specific webpages I get error messages.
google (ncbi nucleotide blast) and click the first link.

In addition to these javascript errors if I click a link which usually opens in a new window, it opens in IE (a separate application).

The 64-bit version seems even more broken.  By going to that same site (ncbi nucleotide blast) I get the entire program crashing due to a 'divide_by_zero' error.

Comment: TWebBrowser is just a wrapper and those errors are not raised by Delphi. To avoid this popups set TWebBrowser.Silent := True

Comment: If I had a penny for every time I saw someone ask this... I'd have a lot of pennies.

Comment: @Sir Rufo Adding .silent got rid of the JS errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the floating point exceptions, `TWebBrowser` expects to operate with floating point exceptions masked. It looks like you are using Delphi default floating point settings and have exceptions unmasked. I suspect that if you mask exceptions then your problems will disappear.

Do that like so:

```
SetExceptionMask(exAllArithmeticExceptions);
```

And as others have said, you silence the Javascript popups by setting `Silent` to `True`.

Comment: Hi David, I've seen this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359223/delphi-xe2-twebbrowser-float-divide-by-zero   but didn't really understand it.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: I tried   System.Set8087CW($133f); and $1F80 // Disable all fpu exceptions.  But I still get the exact same error.  Both SetSSEExceptionMask(exAllArithmeticExceptions) and SetFPUExceptionMask(exAllArithmeticExceptions) don't compile even after importing System.math.

Comment: You are compiling for 64 bit?

Comment: Then it's no good setting 8087CW since that's not used. You need to control the SSE unit. `SetMXCSR($1F80)`

Comment: That totally fixed it!  Now if I could only figure out how to prevent links from opening new windows in a seperate IE process.

Comment: FWIW, `SetExceptionMask(exAllArithmeticExceptions)` works good here